# Proof of multiple equivalences in elementary set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Can someone give a proof or a formal explanation of how are we justified to use this simpler way of proving equivalences described in below:

As an example, let's say that we want to prove the equivalence of three different statements $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. One sure way to do this is to show that $\alpha \iff \beta$, $\beta \iff \gamma$, and $\alpha \iff \gamma$ which is equivalent to proving six different conditionals.

But in my textbook I've seen that the author had used a different approach for a similar situation involving the equivalence of three different statements. 
Instead of the way I've shown in above he proved that $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$, $\beta \Rightarrow \gamma$, and $\gamma\Rightarrow \alpha$.

**One short note:** I searched a lot but I couldn't find any similar question to get my answer. So if you already know a similar question which makes my question a duplicate please inform me to remove my question entirely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\alpha\iff\beta$, for example. This statement is the same as $(\alpha\implies \beta)\wedge( \beta\implies\alpha)$. The first statement we get for free. Then, by modus ponens, since $\beta\implies\gamma$ and $\gamma\implies \alpha$, we have $\beta\implies\alpha$.

Comment: This is the first time I’ve ever seen *modus ponens* instead of *transitivity*. Very interesting…

Comment: I think modus ponens also applies but I may be wrong.

Comment: This is the first I've ever even heard of it so I really don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You can infer the implications the other way by using the transitivity of implication.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\alpha\implies\beta  \text{ and  } \beta\implies\gamma \right) \implies ( \alpha\implies\gamma ).
\end{eqnarray*}